# BigQuery ML Model - Find Original SQL Statements

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

In BigQuery, how can I find the original BigQuery SQL statements used to create a model if the query was not saved?

From a saved BigQuery ML model, I was not able to find the original BigQuery SQL statement code used to create the model.

Comment: Welcome - I am not sure you can, I always save the code I used to create my model in a view alongside the model file that is generated in BQ. It would be really useful to be able to reference back to the SQL in the model insights.

Comment: Maybe you can find it when searching in the project history tab

Comment: Hi @Ben P and p13rr0m, your tips are useful. 
\n
I encountered a challenge where the BigQuery model was created by another team member who didn't save the original 'query'. Within the 'Project History' tab, after filtering for 'Type: Query', GCP only showed my queries. So a workaround is to ask my team member to retrieve the original 'query' from their account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be a chance you can find it using below search query.

Check your **model name**, **creation time** and **region** from *model details* in BigQuery console and modify below query accordingly.

```sql
SELECT query
  FROM `region-us`.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT
 WHERE creation_time BETWEEN '2022-06-16 00:00:00' AND '2022-06-16 23:59:59' 
   AND SEARCH(query, 'your_model_name')
 ORDER BY creation_time DESC;
```

output:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Jaytiger. Your answer was helpful!

For anyone who encounters some issue, remember to grant user permission to query INFORMATION_SCHEMA.JOBS_BY_PROJECT.